# ElasticSearch SearchKick multiple aggs with options in same query

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, searchkick

In the SearchKick documentation there a two ways/styles of requesting Aggs that are mentioned.

For simple (multiple) Agg requests:

```
products = Product.search "chuck taylor", aggs: [:product_type, :gender, :brand]
```

And for Agg requests with options:

```
Product.search "wingtips", aggs: {size: {where: {color: "brandy"}}}
```

My question is - how do we go about declaring multiple aggs with options? We've tried various combinations of the two without success...

For example - this doesn't work...

```
products = Product.search "chuck taylor", aggs: [:product_type, {size: {where: {color: "brandy"}}}]
```

Is it a ruby formatting problem? or is it a limitation in the gem?

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

For those that are looking for the answer:

> you can do:
>
> `products = Product.search "chuck taylor", aggs: 
>                 {product_type: {}, size: {where: {color: "brandy"}}}`

https://github.com/ankane/searchkick/issues/689